# Default objects and default properties in a function's parameters

Tags: javascript

If I've an object argument that may or may not be present, and values that may or may not be in that object, I can provide defaults that look like this:

```
  function doSomthing({id = 'na', name = 'na'} = {id: 'na', name: 'na'}) {}
```

I was just wondering if there was a way of preventing the repetition of the default values in both the deconstructed object and the default object? It just becomes a pretty unweildy definition with larger objects.

Comment: You may consider using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) if you want to *reduce* redundancy (something like `res = Object.assign(defaultsObj, paramsObj)`). Like so you won't need to have object deconstruction either.

Comment: AFAIK the only way to make your example terser is to roll your own default argument functionality using `Object.assign`. This may or may not be an improvement.

Comment: Ok great, thanks, I was just concerned that perhaps I'd missed something back when I was learning about deconstructing

Comment: would desctructuring the whole object help?
Something in the lines of this
`
let defaults = {a:1,b:2} //can also be defined in the function
function f(payload){
let {a,b} = {...defaults,...payload} //note, that we just get the keys of relevance here
return [a,b]
}`
This is not in the signature, but gives more control within the code.
Maybe you can elaborate what you are trying to achieve